# Displaying only next <li> element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I started do learn jQuery few days ago and it seems that i have problem.I am using jquery to "toggle" only next "li" element on hovering, but when i hover it it toggle them all.
Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<div class="A1">
<ul >zeljezo
    <li><a href="#">aa</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>zeljezo
    <li><a href="#">aa</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".A1 ul li").hide();
    $(".A1 ul").hover(function() {
    $(".A1 ul").find("li").slideToggle("fast");
 }); 
});
```

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/tm43Y/2/)**

Comment: Your html is wrong as well, you must write content should be wrapped in li like <li>zeljezo <a href="#">aa</a></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `this` reference inside the hover function to target the currently hovering element,

```
$(".A1 ul").hover(function() {
   $(this).find("li").stop(true).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tm43Y/4/)

And as a side note, clear the animation queue before starting a new animation by using `.stop()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using $(this)

http://jsfiddle.net/tm43Y/3/

```
$(this).find("li").slideToggle("fast");
```

Comment: Also glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must write correct html to avoid cross browsers issues or html errors.
http://jsfiddle.net/h6cFR/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".A1 ul li a").hide();
    $(".A1 ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("a").stop().slideToggle("fast");
  }); 
});
```

correct html code with css :

```
<style>
.A1 li a {
    display:block;
}
</style>

<div class="A1">
        <ul >
            <li>zeljezo
    <a href="#">aa</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>zeljezo<a href="#">aa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```